# Binding duplicate events by using clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

i already duplicate my html elements by this javascript code but i cannot copy the events of the code.Will you gyups please prove me the possible solution.

```js
 <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
  
  
  function func_addmore(){
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("div").click(function () {
               $(this).clone().insertAfter(this);
  
            });
         });
   
  }
      </script>
```

```html
 <body id="show" onload="func_load()">

<form method="POST" action="get_value.php" >
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <td  width="1%"><span> Level of Education:</span></td>
       <td >
     <select id="title" name="title" >
      <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
      <option id="1">Masters</option>
      <option id="2">Bachelors</option>
   <option id="3">HSC</option>
   <option id="4">SSC</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><span>Exam/Degee Title:</span></td>
    <td ><input name="degreetitle"  type="text" id="name" size="19" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  
  
     <tr>
    <td><span>Concentration/Major:</span></td>
    <td><input name="major"  type="text" id="name" size="19" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
  
    <td><span>Institutions:</span></td>
    <td>
     <select id="institutions" name="institutions" onchange="func_ins()">
      <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
      <option id="1">A</option>
      <option id="2">Others</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  
  
   <tr id ="trins">
    <td><span>Others</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="others_ins"  /></td>
  </tr>
  
  
      <tr>
  
    <td><span>Result:</span></td>
    <td>
     <select id="result" name="result" onchange="func_res()">
      <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
      <option id="1">Grade</option>
      <option id="2"   >Division</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr id ="trgrade">
    <td><span>Grade</span>
    <td><input type="text" id="others_grade" size="5"  /></td>
 </tr>
 
 
 
 <tr id ="trscale">
    <td><span>Scale:</span>
    <td><input type="text" id="others_grade" size="5"  /></td>
 </tr>
 
 
     <tr id="trdiv" onload="func_hid()" >
  
    <td><span>Division:</span></td>
    <td>
     <select id="division" name="division">
      <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
      <option id="1">1st Division</option>
      <option id="2">2nd Division</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  width="1%"><span> Year of Passing:</span></td>
       <td >
     <select id="title" name="title" >
      <option value="none" selected >----Select ----</option>
      <option id="1">2016</option>
      <option id="2">2015</option>
   <option id="3">2014</option>
   <option id="4">2013</option>
    <option id="5">2012</option>
     <option id="6">2011</option>
   <option id="7">2010</option>
   <option id="1">2009</option>
      <option id="2">2008</option>
   <option id="3">2007</option>
   <option id="4">2006</option>
    <option id="5">2005</option>
     <option id="6">2004</option>
   <option id="7">2003</option>
   <option id="1">2002</option>
      <option id="2">2001</option>
   <option id="3">2000</option>
   <option id="4">1999</option>
    <option id="5">1998</option>
     <option id="6">1997</option>
   <option id="7">1996</option>
   <option id="1">1995</option>
      <option id="2">1994</option>
   <option id="3">1993</option>
   <option id="4">1992</option>
    <option id="5">1991</option>
     <option id="6">1990</option>
   <option id="7">1989</option>
     <option id="2">1988</option>
   <option id="3">1987</option>
   <option id="4">1986</option>
    <option id="5">1985</option>
     <option id="6">1984</option>
   <option id="7">1983</option>
    <option id="5">1982</option>
     <option id="6">1981</option>
   <option id="7">1980</option>
   
   
   
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  
    <tr>
    <td ><span>Duration:</span></td>
    <td ><input name="duration"  type="text" id="name" size="19" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  
  
  
  
  <tr>
    <td ><span>Achievement:</span></td>
    <td ><input name="achievement"  type="text" id="name" size="19" class=""/></td>
  </tr>
  
  

  
  
 <tr><td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </td></tr>
    
   <tr><td> <input type="button" name="addmore" value="Add more" onclick="func_addmore()" />
  </td></tr>
  
  
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance.I hope i will find out my answer through you guys.Thank you.

Comment: You cannot sue clone. `:P`

Comment: When you say events you mean the `onchange` etc. events on the div attributes right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `.clone()` method offers the option to also clone events. Please note that by default **this option is not used**. In order to clone events you need to use:

```
$(this).clone(true).insertAfter(this);
```

More detail at [jQuery.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: when i use .clone(true) it will call onclick event and add same <div="container" >.... </div>  elements consecutively but i want to do the specific event handle based on specific combobox.By the way thanks mate for reply...

Answer (score 0):

I want to note that the [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method in **jQuery** only clones DOM elements. In order to clone JavaScript objects, you would do:

```
// Shallow copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

More information can be found in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

I also want to note that the deep copy is actually much smarter than what is shown above – it's able to avoid many traps (trying to deep extend a DOM element, for example). It's used frequently in jQuery core and in plugins to great effect.